# Column 'Book.ISBN' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

When I execute the following query I receive the error:
`Column 'Book.ISBN' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`.

```
select Book.ISBN, Book.A, Book.P, Book.Title, Book._Type, A.number
from Book,
    (select  count(*) as number, Book.ISBN, Book._Type
     from Book inner join Borrowed 
            on Book.ISBN = Borrowed.ISBN 
     group by Book.ISBN, Book._Type) A
where Book.ISBN = A.ISBN
group by Book._Type
```

Comment: The error message says it all. You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: You need to do some aggregation function on the fields which you don't group on.

Comment: (Unrelated) Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this exception just the first time; when  you use group by, you mus include all the columns you want to show in the group by, or, use aggregate functions like sum, max, min etc. because the group need just one value for each group.

Answer (score 1):

In your query you don't need the `Group By` clause because you are not grouping by any attribute. So in theory this would be sufficient:

```
select Book.ISBN, Book.A, Book.P, Book.Title, Book._Type, A.number
from Book,
    (select count(*) as number, Book.ISBN, Book._Type
     from Book inner join Borrowed 
            on Book.ISBN = Borrowed.ISBN 
     group by Book.ISBN, Book._Type) A
where Book.ISBN = A.ISBN
```

However, to answer your question, you are getting this error because you need to group all the attributes in the `SELECT` statement. So you need to either remove the `GROUP BY` completely or else add all attributes in the `SELECT` to the `GROUP BY`.

As a rule, you need to only use grouping when you are aggregating in your `SELECT` statement. So in simple terms, when you are using functions such as `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, `COUNT` etc. A list of all the common functions can be accessed [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/index_alpha.php).